# Execute T-SQL Alter Statements created from SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, adventureworks

End Goal: Change specific options of specific indexes in T-SQL.

Setup: SQL Server Express Install / SQL Server Management Studio 19 / Database = AdventureWorks2019

I have the following SELECT statement that queries for the indexes I want to change the row_locking/page_locking options of

```
select 'alter index '+ I.name +' on ' + s.name +'.'+ t.name + ' set (allow_row_locks = off, allow_page_locks = off);' 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS DDIPS
INNER JOIN sys.tables T on T.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas S on T.schema_id = S.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes I ON I.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
AND DDIPS.index_id = I.index_id
WHERE DDIPS.database_id = DB_ID()
and I.name is not null
AND DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 0;
```

This creates a series of results that I would want to execute.

Example row:

```
alter index PK_EmployeePayHistory_BusinessEntityID_RateChangeDate on HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory set (allow_row_locks = off, allow_page_locks = off);
```

As far as I know right now is that I would have to manually copy the result set from the select statement then execute it as its own query, I was looking for a way to automate this process into one or more scripts.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: You can fetch the result into a cursor, iterate over it and execute the query with `EXECUTE` or `sp_executesql`.

Comment: Or just past the results into a SSMS window and run the code.

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from user "sticky bit" - I was able to make the script to include sp_executesql and iterate over the ALTER commands.

Below is how I got it to do the trick.

```
USE AdventureWorks2019;
GO

DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(255);
DECLARE Index_Cursor CURSOR FOR
select 'alter index '+ I.name +' on ' + s.name +'.'+ t.name + ' set (allow_row_locks = off, allow_page_locks = off);' 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS DDIPS
INNER JOIN sys.tables T on T.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas S on T.schema_id = S.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes I ON I.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
AND DDIPS.index_id = I.index_id
WHERE DDIPS.database_id = DB_ID()
and I.name is not null
AND DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 0;

OPEN Index_Cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM Index_Cursor INTO @SQLString;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString;

    FETCH NEXT FROM Index_Cursor INTO @SQLString;
END

CLOSE Index_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Index_Cursor;
GO
```

Comment: `DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(max);` and make sure to use `QUOTENAME` on table and index references. Where possible, pass data into `sp_executesql` via parameters (not relevant in this example)